# What is difference between these two code blocks?

Tags: java, android, xml

Running on Android Studios, Asking for user to enter info. in edit texts and then same showing on Text Views after clicking the submit button these lines written inside method that is called when button is pressed.
These values are defined in XML file already

```
fNameTextView="First Name :" , 
lNameTextView="Last Name :" , 
emailTextView="eMail Id :", 
phoneNumberTextView="Phone Number :"
```

Looking at this code :

```
 public void WhenButtonClicked(){ 
  //function called when button is clicked 
  fNameTextView.setText("First Name :"+fNameEditText.getText().toString()); //text view to display fname
   
  // What is the difference between above block and below block of code?
  fNameTextView.setText(fNameTextView.getText()+fNameEditText.getText().toString()); //textview to display     
}
```

What is the difference between the two code statements?

Comment: Someone please help me to understand this question x_x.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first example the value is a hard-coded string, and in the second example, it obtains the configured value.

It may currently produce the same output, but if you changed the configuration for `fNameTextView`, you would also need to update the first code statement if you wanted it to match.

With the second code statement, it would "just work". Less maintenance, less repetition, more consistency.